# Topology for the set of all atlases on a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Is there a way to endow with a topology the set of all atlases of a given topological manifold $M$ ?

Which are the properties of this topology with respect to $M$ ? It would be very nice if this topology have paths between atlases which in some way correspond to isotopies between $(M,\Phi)$ and $(M,\Psi)$ where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are two atlases on $M$

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give some examples of specific points, maybe paths in the suggested space?

Comment: What is the purpose of topologizing the set of atlases?

Comment: I am working with manifolds and I have come to the point where I have a map from a topological space into the set of all atlases o a given topological manifold$M$. I would like this map to be continuous with this topology. I did a search on the net but I found nothing. I just wanted to know if there was some known topology on the set of all atlases on $M$

Comment: What is that map?

Comment: The map is of the form $f\colon X \to \mathcal{A}$ where $X$ is a topological space,  \mathcal{A} os the set of all atlases on $M$ and $f$ is surjective.